# Objective C - problem when converting data to NSString by encoding use NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to read UTF-8 data sent from Java server on iphone

```
            uint8_t buf[1024];

            unsigned int len = 0;

            len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1024];

            if(len) {
```

with this :

```
NSString *chrStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)buf length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

when buf has length < 129 , the conversion is ok. but if length > 129, chrStr is return null

If i Change encoding by NSASCIIStringEncoding :

```
NSString *chrStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)buf length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

the conversion is ok with length > 129 but UTF8 characters is incorrectly :(

sorry for my Enghlish.

Comment: Check whether the characters past 129 are actually valid UTF-8. Does this happen to every string with length > 129 or to a particular string only?

Answer (score 2):

`-[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` does work with strings longer than 129 bytes.

You problem is elsewhere.

Edit to answer comment:

As I said, you problem origins **not from the length** but from some other issue. As @Bavarious speculated, your string might not be valid UTF-8.

The following code works as expected:

```
const char* c_string = "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:c_string
                                             length:strlen(c_string)
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
assert([string length] == strlen(c_string)); // only valid for ASCII
```

If you still think -[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:] might not work as expected, please post code along with the string in question.

Comment: when len = 130 , the String I wrote is "aa...aaa" // 130 words . -[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] . chrStr return Null . If len < 130 , it return correctly .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're reading a partial UTF8 string into "buf". I.e., on the next read from the stream you might get some trailing bytes because your UTF-8 encoded character has been split in the middle.